# How can I hide buttons in Create mode and show buttons in Edit mode only?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have Reports and Form in oracle APEX ,
I need to hide the buttons in CREATE mode and I need to show the buttons in Edit mode

`I can hide the buttons in both CREATE and EDIT mode from server-side condition and select Never`

but how to show on EDIT mode only where I can add the condition to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
1- Click the button

2- Go to server-side condition 

3- Select the Type Item is NOT NULL 

4- Select your primary key item 

5- SAVE changes
```

because in CREATE MODE still your primary key value still not created but in EDIT mode primary key created and you need to EDIT.